# When using EWS from within a website, is it possible to use the current logged in users identity?

Tags: asp.net, email, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have a web application using Forms authentication provided by AD.

I would like to know if it's possible to use EWS to send mail as the currently logged in user without having to supply credentials, or; would I be required to set up an account with impersonating access which will send mail on behalf of the currently logged in user?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. If your process runs (or impersonated) as a user having a mailbox you will access all the stuff without specifying any credentials.

Comment: Yes, but I want to send email as the current user logged in to the web application, not the user that IIS is running as. So is the only way to get this to work to setup impersonating access within AD for the user that IIS is running as?

Comment: IF your users come from the company network, you can enable windows authentication within your asp.net application so your security will already be based on impersonation and you don't have to do anything.
If your users come from internet and don't have accounts in company network, you can create a superuser in exchange which has ReceiveAs permission to the mailboxes you need access to. In this case all you need is specify superuser credentials.